# Display 2 Grid layout in admin form

Tags: magento-1.7, xml, grid-layout

I have create one custom tab in my module and display one grid output successfully, but my question is how we can display two grid serializer block in one page? I have tried to out put with calling two serializer block with this code.

```
public function customgridAction()

{
   $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('regionpage.productgrid')->setProductsGrid($this->getRequest()->getPost('products_grid', null));
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('regionpage.articlegrid')->setArticlesGrid($this->getRequest()->getPost('articles_grid', null));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

And this is what my layout xml look like

```
<regionpage_adminhtml_regionpage_customgrid>
<block type="core/text_list" name="root">
    <block type="regionpage/adminhtml_regionpage_edit_tab_productgrid" name="regionpage.productgrid"/>
    <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="regionpage_productgrid">
        <reference name="regionpage_productgrid">
            <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                <grid_block_name>regionpage.productgrid</grid_block_name>
                <data_callback>getSelectedProducts</data_callback>
                <hidden_input_name>links[productgrid]</hidden_input_name>
                <reload_param_name>products_grid</reload_param_name>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnInputName">
                <input_name>position</input_name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </block>
</block>
```

```
 <regionpage_adminhtml_regionpage_customgrid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root">
        <block type="regionpage/adminhtml_regionpage_edit_tab_articlegrid" name="regionpage.articlegrid"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="regionpage_articlegrid">
            <reference name="regionpage_articlegrid">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>regionpage.articlegrid</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedArticles</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[articlegrid]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>articles_grid</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
 </regionpage_adminhtml_regionpage_customgrid>
```

But it output last block not both block.

I had asked this question on stackoverflow sometimes ago but not getting any answer so i thought to reposted it here

I have seen this meta question [Can I repost unanswered questions from Stack Overflow?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/can-i-repost-unanswered-questions-from-stack-overflow)
So I have reposted this question again here.

Stackoverflow question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972662/grid-layout-in-magento

Comment: This is a good article on how grid's work, from what I can tell, I don't see any reason why you can't have two grids, what does your layout.xml look like? http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/how-does-magento-adminhtml-grid-work.html

Comment: i have refer this link http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/understanding-the-grid-serializer-block/ and how magento display upsell, cross sell product grid

Comment: What does your layout look like?

Comment: @davidalger I had added my layout

Comment: what happens if you wrap the getBlocks in your controller with $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->getBlock(''), 'block_name');

Comment: yes but i am not getting getSelectedProducts if i use this method

Comment: does $this->getLayout()->getBlock('regionpage.productgrid'); return a block or a boolean?

Comment: it returns block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I have cracked it.

The problem appears to be when you are using the wrapping block

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="root">
```

Once you have defined a block of name "root" then it will be overridden if another block with the same name comes along later. (Correct me if I am wrong)

There are two solutions you could try.

1. Combine both your xml into one section

Which would make your xml as follows

```
<regionpage_adminhtml_regionpage_customgrid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root">
    <block type="regionpage/adminhtml_regionpage_edit_tab_productgrid" name="regionpage.productgrid"/>
    <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="regionpage_productgrid">
        <reference name="regionpage_productgrid">
            <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                <grid_block_name>regionpage.productgrid</grid_block_name>
                <data_callback>getSelectedProducts</data_callback>
                <hidden_input_name>links[productgrid]</hidden_input_name>
                <reload_param_name>products_grid</reload_param_name>
            </action>
            <action method="addColumnInputName">
                <input_name>position</input_name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </block>
    <block type="regionpage/adminhtml_regionpage_edit_tab_articlegrid" name="regionpage.articlegrid"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="regionpage_articlegrid">
            <reference name="regionpage_articlegrid">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>regionpage.articlegrid</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedArticles</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[articlegrid]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>articles_grid</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
</regionpage_adminhtml_regionpage_customgrid>
```

1. Simple replace in your second section the follow section

With a reference node which would make your second section look like

```
<regionpage_adminhtml_regionpage_customgrid>
    <reference name="root">
    <block type="regionpage/adminhtml_regionpage_edit_tab_articlegrid" name="regionpage.articlegrid"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="regionpage_articlegrid">
            <reference name="regionpage_articlegrid">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>regionpage.articlegrid</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedArticles</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[articlegrid]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>articles_grid</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </block>
    </reference>
</regionpage_adminhtml_regionpage_customgrid>
```

Hope this fixes it and is a good enough explanation :)